# Error in compilation of "Hello World" program

Tags: c, macos, codeblocks

I am trying to run a simple program below on my mac using CodeBlocks IDE:

```
    1.  #include <stdio.h>

    2.  int main()
    3.  {
    4.     // printf() displays the string inside quotation
    5.     printf("Hello, World!");
    6.     return 0;
    7.  }
```

but I get the following error:

> error: expected identifier or '('

As the machine is trying to compile, I think gcc compiler is working fine.

Comment: error on which line number?

Comment: Are those line numbers included in the file?

Comment: Is that the entire error? You don’t get „error: expected identifier or ‘(’ *before numeric constant*“ by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Remove the line numbers, that's the problem.**

Answer (score 0):

try in different IDE and find out where the problem is whether in Codeblocks IDE configuration or with the compiler itself.